# Howto build a field value in a Model derived from values in another Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, exists, distinct-values

A model of the system has a **Party Model**.

```
class Party(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    our_reference = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Peter is a party, and another person with the same name is also called Peter. The field "our_reference" should use the first three chars, followed by an int, like PET1. The second Peter will be PET2. A third person is added, called Petras. He will be PET3.

Using the Levenshtein module (https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html) we need to test, on insertion of a party, whether that party already exists, like -

`def get_similar_items(mod, field, string, similarity_ratio=0.6, limit=None):
    """ 
        Get similar items for a specific model
        Example usage:
        similar = get_similar_items(Entry, 'title', 'Espresso is good for you', 0.5, 10)
        var = Entry.objects.filter(id__in=similar)
    """
    similar_list_id = []
    v = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(mod)
    c = v.model_class()
    for i in c.objects.all():
        if ratio(string, getattr(i,field)) > similarity_ratio:
            similar_list_id.append(i.id)
    return similar_list_id[:limit]`
 
seen at https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/288/

If the party exist, don't use a new int number but use the old, one i.e. PET1 as a reference. If the party does not exist, make a new reference PET4.

The question was edited to make the use case clearer. How to implement?

Comment: Eventually decided to go with a simple solution - use UUID's as suggested by knelson and a normal postgres sequence. `code`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like instead of adding the party's initials and the instruction number together in one field called `our_reference`, it would be better to save only the reference number, since you can pull the initials from the fk to the party.

This would make incrementing the instruction number much easier.

So change `our_reference` to a int field.

Whenever you want to add a new case, check to see if the party already exists. You may want to have an identifier other than solely by name, as two people can have the same name.

If the party does not exist, create one and grab the first three characters of the name, `str(party.name[3:]).upper()`.

To get new instruction numbers, you can find all instructions that the party already has be using [related_names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Write something along the lines of:

> new_instruction_number_for_party = max(party.instructions.all().values_list('our_reference')) + 1

Finally, when displaying the total file reference in a template, add both `our_reference` and the first three letters to context and in the template put `{{ party_initials }}{{ num_of_initial }}/{{ our_reference }}`.

Comment: UUID's are used so the foreign key will not work out of the box - it is my understanding that UUID's work better for multi-tenant platforms. Will give your approach a bash and will post a solution if I can.

Comment: I am going back to the original question, because it is the right way to do it. @knelson say that **You may want to have an identifier other than solely by name, as two people can have the same name**. That is the point; many people share the same name and surname, same goes for organizations. So, maybe a person/organization is identified by the first part of the identifier i.e. DOE1. Another person with the same name will be identified by DOE2. In DOE1 there can be multiple files, same for DOE2.

Comment: [name_tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/name_tools) provides a measure of the similarity between two names. Maybe use [python_nameparser](https://github.com/derek73/python-nameparser) to handle the concatenated fields and then pass to name_tools to check whether the person exists.